# SQS AWS - message.acknowledge - exception with acknowledge mode: UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE

Tags: amazon-web-services, jms, amazon-sqs

I was running the SyncMessageReceiverUnorderedAcknowledge.java program, exactly as written on: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/jmsclient.html#jmsclient-ackmode

```
public class SyncMessageReceiverUnorderedAcknowledge {

// Visibility time-out for the queue. It must match to the one set for the queue for this example to work.
private static final long TIME_OUT_SECONDS = 1;

public static void main(String args[]) throws JMSException, InterruptedException {
    // Create the configuration for the example
    ExampleConfiguration config = ExampleConfiguration.parseConfig("SyncMessageReceiverUnorderedAcknowledge", args);

    // Setup logging for the example
    ExampleCommon.setupLogging();

    // Create the connection factory based on the config
    SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
                    .withRegion(config.getRegion())
                    .withAWSCredentialsProvider(config.getCredentialsProvider())
                    .build();

    // Create the connection
    SQSConnection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

    // Create the queue if needed
    ExampleCommon.ensureQueueExists(connection, config.getQueueName());

    // Create the session  with unordered acknowledge mode
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, **SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE**);

    // Create the producer and consume
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(session.createQueue(config.getQueueName()));
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(session.createQueue(config.getQueueName()));

    // Open the connection
    connection.start();

    // Send two text messages
    sendMessage(producer, session, "Message 1");
    sendMessage(producer, session, "Message 2");

    // Receive a message and don't acknowledge it
    receiveMessage(consumer, false);

    // Receive another message and acknowledge it
    receiveMessage(consumer, true);

    // Wait for the visibility time out, so that unacknowledged messages reappear in the queue
    System.out.println("Waiting for visibility timeout...");
    Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TIME_OUT_SECONDS));

    // Attempt to receive another message and acknowledge it. This will result in receiving the first message since
    // we have acknowledged only the second message. In the UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE mode, all the messages must
    // be explicitly acknowledged.
    receiveMessage(consumer, true);

    // Close the connection. This will close the session automatically
    connection.close();
    System.out.println("Connection closed.");
}

/**
 * Sends a message through the producer.
 *
 * @param producer Message producer
 * @param session Session
 * @param messageText Text for the message to be sent
 * @throws JMSException
 */
private static void sendMessage(MessageProducer producer, Session session, String messageText) throws JMSException {
    // Create a text message and send it
    producer.send(session.createTextMessage(messageText));
}

/**
 * Receives a message through the consumer synchronously with the default timeout (TIME_OUT_SECONDS).
 * If a message is received, the message is printed. If no message is received, "Queue is empty!" is
 * printed.
 *
 * @param consumer Message consumer
 * @param acknowledge If true and a message is received, the received message is acknowledged.
 * @throws JMSException
 */
private static void receiveMessage(MessageConsumer consumer, boolean acknowledge) throws JMSException {
    // Receive a message
    Message message = consumer.receive(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TIME_OUT_SECONDS));

    if (message == null) {
        System.out.println("Queue is empty!");
    } else {
        // Since this queue has only text messages, cast the message object and print the text
        System.out.println("Received: " + ((TextMessage) message).getText());

        // Acknowledge the message if asked
        if (acknowledge) **message.acknowledge();**
    }
}
```

}

When the below code is reached:

```
// Create the session  with unordered acknowledge mode
Session session = connection.createSession(false,SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE);
// Acknowledge the message if asked
if (acknowledge) message.acknowledge();
```

I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS.deleteMessage(Lcom/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/DeleteMessageRequest;)V**
> at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.deleteMessage(AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.java:127)
> at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.acknowledge.UnorderedAcknowledger.acknowledge(UnorderedAcknowledger.java:42)
> at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.message.SQSMessage.acknowledge(SQSMessage.java:883)
> at sample.sqs.SyncMessageReceiverUnorderedAcknowledge.receiveMessage(SyncMessageReceiverUnorderedAcknowledge.java:116)
> at sample.sqs.SyncMessageReceiverUnorderedAcknowledge.main(SyncMessageReceiverUnorderedAcknowledge.java:67)

I am running with the following gradle dependencies:

> compile("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:1.11.13")
>
> compile("com.amazonaws:amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib:1.0.0")

I debugged the code, and all the aws amazon java classes looks perfect.

In addition, I created a new program that will run isolated deleteMessage.
With deleteMessage(DeleteMessageRequest deleteMessageRequest) - **I get the same exception**.

But With DeleteMessageBatchResult deleteMessageBatch(DeleteMessageBatchRequest deleteMessageBatchRequest) - Which is in the same classes - **It works!**

I cleaned the gradle cache folder, downloaded again all the jars, vlean, build, but I get the same results :-(

Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib/issues/22

I changed gradle dependencies:
compile("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:1.9.6")

And now it works perfect.

Opening pom.xml of amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib project, I can see:

```
<properties> <aws-java-sdk.version>1.9.6</aws-java-sdk.version> </properties>
```

I wonder when do AWS team plan to change it to the latest one (e.g. 1.11.13)? or one of the latest.